# Spaceships can't land, and no ships are coming. How to keep the crew alive?

Tags: warfare, spaceships

I've been happily writing along in my story for a bit, but now I've realized that I have no way to refuel/get cargo to my ships. Before, I had a few large ships that could, if needed, hold another ship and transfer cargo. These ships are still there, but will run out of supplies soon. However, after aliens blew up the mars colony launch pads and filled earth's orbits with tons of metal canisters so nothing can get in or out, the space fleet is in a bit of a bad spot. With nothing coming from mars until the launch pads are rebuilt, and earth surrounded by high speed metal canisters, how do I keep the crews alive, at least for six months when mars can send a supply ship?

current ship supplies-

- Ammunition, varies by ship, but there's enough to blow up something about half the size of the moon
- Food for three months. Won't last six, no matter how you stretch it
- Water, also for three months. Won't last six months.

I want to try and keep the entire space fleet alive. If there is no other option, I can kill off half of the crews, although I'd like to avoid this as much as possible. *NO CANNIBALISM*

Another question- the spaceships can't enter atmosphere or land, since they don't have landing gear or retro rockets. How would I use a supply ship(unarmed, only enough fuel to get it to the fleet, not even airtight and flown by a basic AI) so that I don't waste anything? As a diversion? A suicide bomber? Repair parts?

Comment: This will be tough, since it's apparently more cost effective to ship food from another planet than it is to grow it where it's needed. Evidently, growing an ear of corn on Earth costs more than growing one on Mars and shipping it tens of millions of miles. Unless interplanetary travel has become absurdly cheap, these starving earthlings will have to replace an expensive supply chain with an even more expensive option.

Comment: @NuclearWang, earth can't send any supplies because there are tons of metal debris bits clogging up the orbits. nothing can get in or out of there now.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b,
can't you have a part of your fleet blow up enough of the debris to clear a path?
Use unmanned drones or your own debris or something similar.
Shoot it with LASERS or missiles. 
Use something like a bulldozer to clear enough of it?
Heck. Have a suicide mission to clear a part of the debris. 
Though unmanned stuff is the most reasonable.

Comment: Remember if it is good enough to answer it is good enough to upvote!

Comment: "How do I use X to solve Y?" is a question to be resolved by your story.

Comment: Do you have cryogenic sleep chambers?

Comment: Perhaps moon colony or even just a depot?

Answer (score 7):

**Water recycling, drug-induced comas, hydroponics, and shooting water bottles:**

Water isn't going anywhere, unless your crew makes a habit of venting the stuff into space. I don't think that your fleet would be dumping it, but recycling it all along - it just makes sense not to be wasteful. If they weren't all along, I think that would be easy to set up. People can starve a long time and be alive, but without water, you're screwed.

I agree that cryosleep would be the best option, but we can assume that they would be using it if it was available. Assuming it's NOT available, there is a poor-man's option, full of dramatic risk and tragic loss. You can use drugs to shut down the metabolisms of many of the crew, drastically reducing their caloric intake. Most of the equipment, in the form of catheters, temp-controlled rooms, etc. should be available. This is the poor man's cryostasis, but I would guess your people would have the stuff for it ready, as a contingency for just such a situation (it's the grist of so many space movies...)

If you want a simple alternative, the drugs can still lower metabolism, but not knock out anyone - your crews are stumbling around in a constant fatigue haze, cold but unable to shiver and sleeping all the time.

I THINK that your scenario involves a fleet of ships in orbit around Earth, who can't be resupplied by Earth, and are waiting for supplies from Mars. Even if it's a suicide mission, supplies from the Earth can be sent - you'll just lose lots of robotic supply ships. Robotic ships might even be able to handle being punched through with holes, and supplies might freeze, get damaged, but so what? Dribble just enough stuff to get your folks through.

If you have ammo enough to blow away half the moon, can you blow openings in the debris field around the planet? I don't know what kind of weapons they are, but something like this has been proposed in a few stories, where debris is blocking the space around Earth.

You can always use improvised low grav hydroponics, much like the potato growing from *The Martian*, but on your ships. It wouldn't be a complete option, but every bit counts, and all that human waste shouldn't GO to waste.

As for how to use a resupply ship - well, obviously for supplies. After that, you haven't given us enough in-story context to guess, and I think that would be outside worldbuilding.

Comment: I like the idea of the robot supply ships limping in, with their various wounds then examined by the survivors..  "Holy crap what could make a hole like this?"  "Not an F series railgun.  That must have been a missile.  Or orbiting debris."

Answer (score 5):

**Alien food.**

During the battle with the aliens, a lot of ships from both sides were disabled or wrecked.  Those ships are still floating along the trajectories they had when they were disabled.  The human ships of course have all the stuff needed for their crews but by now the human survivors have been rescued and the salvageables salvaged.

That leaves the drifting alien ships.  Who knows what might be on them?  Something to eat, maybe?  One way to find out.

Comment: Maybe the aliens are tasty ^.^

Comment: Would be canibalism take those aliens foes as dinner?

Answer (score 5):

"Hey, we forgot about X"

- Your folks on Earth were conveniently experimenting with a railgun on the side of a mountain, an experiment to eventually replace expensive rockets. People would be pulped by the acceleration, but lots of cargo can handle it. Numerous small capsules full of food will fly between the orbit-denial canisters. Some will get smashed, but  so what? The fleet simply needs to catch the capsules at apogee...before they fall back into the ocean.
- There was that big agro complex under the lunar surface. It was mothballed years ago as too big and too expensive to operate when fewer Lunar facilities were built than had been projected...but the small caretaker crew says that it still works, and crops grow fast! The crew is too small operate the complex, so you'll need to find and transport some farmers.
- Remember the prison-asteroid-farm? They were self-sufficient in food a decade ago, and the government just expanded the farm enormously because the warden is corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

**Time it just right to get under the debris shell**

There's a maximum density this debris field can have. At lower altitudes, debris orbits would rapidly degenerate and fall down to Earth. Alternatively, at higher altitudes, there is simply too much volume of space to effectively and economically blockade it with debris. That means the aliens set up a middle-ground: a "shell" of debris that isn't low enough to instantly fall and it isn't so high that the debris density makes it ineffective. That means there's gaps--according to precise mathematical timing, "windows" to the planet and lower orbits open up on mathematically predictable intervals. Then, all you need is a space station or supply dump that's not on the planet but behind the debris shell. This way your non-atmospheric craft can still get supplies.

If you want to write this dramatically, you could have a "genius" sensor officer or whoever figure out the pattern and start predicting "windows" where they could get through to the lower orbits. Unfortunately though, these windows are so short (minutes or seconds long) and rare. This means the ship needs to commit before they see the window, and they need to trust that math-wiz's prediction--if he gets it wrong they all die.

**Find supplies elsewhere**

Pretty straightforward. Historical documents show that there are plenty of old space stations, moon-bases, and relics floating around from the dawn of the space era (from 1950's onwards) and the fleet scours these places to hopefully find long-abandoned supplies. Alternatively, you said the debris-shield was made of "water bottles" so capturing those could solve your water supply issues.

**Put people in cryosleep**

This is a bit of a "deus-ex-machina" answer but you could dust off old cryopods or have someone invent them to put half the crew into stasis for a couple months or until supplies get there. Maybe, there's an abandoned colony ship project floating around somewhere which never got funded to completion or which had it's construction aborted when aliens invaded or whatever. You could steal the cryopods from there.

Comment: good idea with the water bottles, but i just meant there was a bunch of metal canisters orbiting earth at high speeds. water bottles fit the size about right.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b Aha, well you can also find water ice in lunar craters

Answer (score 2):

**Escape Pods.**

I have watched enough episodes of Star Trek to know that every human spaceship comes equipped with escape pods. Not quite sure what they're for, but they seem useful here.

Send the most part of your crew back to the surface of Mars in escape pods. They will help with repairs while the skeleton crew left over can live off the 3 months supplies for years.

Answer (score 2):

**Water**

While water is the most important resource, it's also not a huge issue. First, if you aren't doing it already, recycling water will make you save a lot of it, meaning also recycling pee like they do on the ISS.
Then you can start looking for water around you:

- The Alien ships might hold some, depending on their biology and/or how the ships work.
- In 2019 NASA confirmed that there is solid water (ice) on the dark side of the moon, and in the shadow of some craters on the visible side.
- Comets are often covered in ice, so if you're lucky you might be able to harvest it from those.

As for the tools for the job, you have a fleet. You can probably work something out by taking apart one of the ships (or the supply ships you were talking about) and turning it into a good-enough landing craft to get on the moon maybe (think the Apollo missions LEM, nothing fancy).

**Food**

This really depends on your setting.

- Chances are there is some space station around Mars where they conduct experiments like on the ISS. If so, you have a good chance to find plants and insects ready to be farmed on a larger scale. Recovering some of those would allow you to start farming it, and possibly stretch that food supply a little bit further.
- The Alien ships might hold something interesting. Maybe not what we consider food, but something close enough to be edible.
- From both sources above, as well as your own fleet, you might also want to consider IV fluids. A human can survive months, or even years, on IV fluids alone. Some of your crew could replace food with IV for a while, until supplies last. Depending on how much you had stored and/or found, this could add days or weeks to your food supplies, even more time if you place them in a coma, severely reducing their need for calories.

This might not completely solve the food issue, but it could at least save more people if you really have to start killing someone.

**Other considerations**

- Mars might be able to launch something after all. While a launchpad is required for a safe enough launch, if things were really extreme you could probably work with less-than-ideal pads and simply shoot rockets up. To give you some context, think about the difference between launching one of today's missions vs launching a V2 rocket. Might not be a sure thing, but out of several launches something would get up there.
- Earth's trash problem. I'm not entirely sure of the consequences, but have you considered having your ships blast it? You said you have plenty of weapons/ammo, and you still have supplies for 3 months, meaning you don't have to rush it too much. All you need is to clear enough space to make it safe-ish for an unmanned supply mission to go through it